# Variable Arguments for Riemann project function

Tags: clojure, riemann

So I am working on a stream function which will sum up some metrics for several events. To do this I use the `project` function and it looks something like this:

```
(project [(func (:service event) (nth service-list 0))      
          (func (:service event) (nth service-list 1))
          (func (:service event) (nth service-list 2))]
         (..))
```

`service-list` is a argument of the surrounding function, which contain a vector of services that must be added together. `func` is a function that takes two arguments and returns a `true`/`false` Using the above snippet works fine, but I would like to be able to simplify it so that a vector that is larger or smaller than 3 elements would work.

So far I have this:

```
    (project (mapv (fn[service] (
                   `func (:service event) ~service)
                   ) service-list)))
             (..)
```

which I think returns a vector of functions which are unevaluated. I went with this approach once I realised that `project` is a macro. No idea if I am doing the right thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that you can not dynamically assemble just the arguments of a macro call. Therefore you need to dynamically assemble the whole macro call.

You can build a clojure form and call [eval](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/eval) on it. Take the following.

```
    (let [args (mapv #(list 'func (:service 'event) %) service-list)
          form (list 'project args (...))]
      (eval form))
```

Or, you could also use the [riemann.streams/project*](http://riemann.io/api/riemann.streams.html#var-project*) function to use *predicate functions* instead of *where* expressions.